# Move my robot-Tutorial (General Question)

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am new to ROS (I am using ROS Kinetic) and Gazebo and so far what I have managed to do are the following:

- Create a URDF model of a 4 wheel
  robot with a camera on top, a
  base_link and 4 continuous joints
  (connecting the wheels with the
  base_link) with controllers,transmissions and
  actuators on each one. I also created the appropriate configuration yaml file for the control of my robot.
- Create launch files for rviz and
  gazebo and successfully display my
  robot in these environments.
- Get image from the camera plugin I
  added, in gazebo.

My next step is to move my robot. I searched this [tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_comm), but it is not what I am looking and I am kind of lost right now. I also checked the [MoveIt](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/pr2_moveit_tutorials/html/planning/src/doc/move_group_interface_tutorial.html) C++ beginner tutorial, but it is referring to the PR2 robot and it doesn't help me to start something on my own and build from it.

To be more specific, what I am thinking of doing next is to create nodes (the motors of the robot and the camera) and according to what image I get from the camera, I would send an appropriate command to the motors to either stop or move on, but I cannot find a tutorial that could help me with that. Even a tutorial with simple movement of a robot could help me, i.e. sending to a motor-node to move forward and simulate this movement in gazebo.
If you know a tutorial that could be useful for me to start from, I would appreciate your help.

Thanks for your answers and for your time in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240057/move-my-robot-tutorial-(general-question)/) by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 354 on 2016-07-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The RobotSetup navigation tutorial (http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup) is a good place to start. In particular, the diagram in section 1 of that page shows the relationship between the navigation planners (the box in the middle) and the controller that will set the speeds of the four wheels.

The output of the local planner is a `geometry_msgs/Twist` message on the `/cmd_vel` topic (by default). The controller – which you need to supply – has to convert from the linear x velocity and the angular z velocity to wheel speeds for the four motors. You don't specify much about the hardware, so I don't know which direction to point you. There are packages in ROS such as `ros_control` that are configurable to talk to different hardware. On my robot there is an Arduino-compatible board that controls the motors for a differential-drive robot, so I'm using instead the `ros_arduino_bridge` package as the controller. (Other options for my case include `rosserial_arduino`.)

Once you have a controller in place that listens on the `/cmd_vel` topic, you can send those messages either using `rostopic pub` or using a panel in `rviz`. After you get the controller working you will then need to set up the planners, probably using `move_base`.

---

Originally posted by [Mark Rose](https://answers.ros.org/users/27558/mark-rose/) with karma: 1563 on 2016-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) on 2016-07-22**:
I have added controller_manager and hardware_interface from the ros_control metapackage, taken from this [tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_control). But the commands from the tutorial haven't worked for me, so probably in the future I will change them.

**Comment by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) on 2016-07-22**:
I wanted to ask you about the [link](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup) you sent me. In the section 2.1 Creating a Package it says: `catkin_create_pkg my_robot_name_2dnav move_base my_tf_configuration_dep my_odom_configuration_dep my_sensor_configuration_dep`

**Comment by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) on 2016-07-22**:
Could you please explain me what kind of dependencies it requires. I am referring to `my_tf_configuration_dep my_odom_configuration_dep my_sensor_configuration_dep` .
What packages should I search for?
Thanks for answering and for your time again.

**Comment by [Mark Rose](https://answers.ros.org/users/27558/mark-rose/) on 2016-07-22**:
All but move_base are example dependencies that you *might have*. The three envisioned packages are: URDF for frame defs (`my_tf_configuration_dep`), robot controller (`my_odom_configuration_dep`), and sensor publisher (`my_sensor_configuration_dep`). You could put all in the new package instead.

**Comment by [Mark Rose](https://answers.ros.org/users/27558/mark-rose/) on 2016-07-22**:
In that case, your package creation would be just: `catkin_create_pkg my_robot_name_2dnav move_base`

**Comment by [Mark Rose](https://answers.ros.org/users/27558/mark-rose/) on 2016-07-22**:
Now, what packages should you search for: you need something that provides a robot controller (listening on `/cmd_vel`, publishing on `/odom`) and something that publishes either `PointCloud` or `LaserScan`. What you need depends on your hardware.

**Comment by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) on 2016-07-22**:
So to sum up what I need to is:

- `catkin_create_pkg my_robot_name_2dnav move_base roscpp`
- Create a publisher on the /cmd_vel topic (at my_robot_name_2dnav/src/publisher.cpp)
- Put the controllers I have on my motors to listen to it (create a listener.cpp)
- Simulate it in gazebo

Correct?

**Comment by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) on 2016-07-22**:
My comment refers to just move my robot...I will forget about the sensor for now.

**Comment by [Mark Rose](https://answers.ros.org/users/27558/mark-rose/) on 2016-07-23**:
Yes, the robot controller (one or more nodes) should listen on /cmd_vel and command the motors, and then publish the robot position on /odom. Once you get sensors, publish a PointCloud or LaserScan.